# Impossible to read from ouput stream

Tags: java, sockets, input, output

I have a server that sends a String to a socket client. When I try to get the contents of the String from the client it wouldn't read it.
The server sends via:

```
output.write(res); output.flush(); // I checked res content and it is all good
```

and this the Client receiving:

```
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Socket connexion = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 33333);

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connexion.getInputStream(), "8859_1"), 1024);
    String res="";
    while(input.readLine()!=null){
        res += input.readLine()+"\n";
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}}
```

Suggestions please ? Thank you

Comment: The server doesn't send any newline character. The client expects one. So it blocks until the server sends one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading the next line and then disregarding it, and then trying to read the next line again. The second time you read the next line, there is no data because the first read has already consumed it:

```
while(input.readLine()!=null){
    res += input.readLine()+"\n";
}
```

Try something like the following:

```
String line = null;
while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    res += line + "\n";
}
```

As @JB Nizet mentioned, this is contingent upon the server actually sending a newline character to the client to terminate the message. As stated in the [documentation for `readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

Comment: I tried it. Same problem. If I take off the while loop only the first line of res is printed on the screen

Comment: while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        res+=line+"\n";         
       }
       //System.out.println(res);
       output.write(res); output.flush();                                                                   
This should work! No ? I add a \n after every line

Comment: The issue may not be that the `res` does not have a newline: It may be that the input being read from the socket through `bufferedReader.readLine()` does not contain newlines, so the `readLine` call never returns. See the documentation quoted above.

Comment: Also, your client doesn't print anything until the server closes the socket. Does it close the socket? Have you used your debugger?

Comment: So, I tried to understand the doc but I cant find the problem. I added a \n after ever readLine() and yes I closed my socket just before printing the res variable. Any other suggestions please .?

Comment: @AbderrahmenMrabet The **server** doesn't **send** any newline. Adding newlines in the client won't help. The **server** needs to **send** newlines, and to close the socket.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much. I had only to close the server's Socket. it worked